# Twitter Bootstrap: margin-bottom on small-tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a paragraph of text, sitting in a `p`-tag. Inside this text, there is an image. For that image, I want to add a title below using the `small` tag. This is the HTML code (I added line breaks for better readability):

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <img src="img/myimage.png" alt="myimage" /><small>
Hey look, thats my image!</small><br />consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam</p>
```

Now I want to add a bottom margin to the `small`-tag using this CSS-code:

```
p small {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

It is not working, no `margin-bottom` is applied. The selector is right as I can change the left margin, text color and so on.

*How do I add a `margin-bottom` to `small` in Twitter Bootstrap?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p small` is an `inline` item, and you can't add margins to inline items. Try:

```
p small {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The only drawback about `inline-block` is that you might run into cross-browser compatibility issues.

In your specific example, perhaps you can wrap the `img` and `small` in a div, then define:

```
p small {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I had suspected that I have to wrap the elements, thanks!